# Why does spark-submit fail with “Error executing Jupyter command”?

Tags: java, macos, apache-spark, jupyter

When trying to run Spark locally on my Mac (which used to work) ...

```sh
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java \
-cp /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.0/libexec/conf/:/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.0/libexec/jars/* \
-Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit \
--packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.0 \
/Users/crump/main.py
```

I'm now getting the following error:

```
Error executing Jupyter command '/Users/crump/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The file is there.  Since I know this used to work, I must have installed something recently that changed a library, sdk, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer finally:  `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter` in my environment. I set this up to launch Jupyter/Spark notebooks with just the pyspark command, but it causes spark-submit to fail.

The solution is set the variable to use python, not jupyter:  `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python.`

Comment: Even though `spark-submit` does not work, you can still execute the script using `python my-spark-script.py` without having to change the environment variable.